# Why aren't my songs from iTunes actually syncing to my iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization

I just put a bunch of songs on my iPod, and most of them worked. But now there’s two more that I need to download and when I drag and drop the files to the "Music" section of my iPod, the songs show up there, but they have that symbol next to them that suggests they are still syncing, and they are gray. But it's been like that for like three hours. So I know they are not actually syncing. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried syncing internally from iTunes? As in put the music into a playlist, and sync the whole playlist from the syncing tab?

Answer (score 1):

You can also uncheck the songs in iTunes, sync with whatever device you are using, then recheck the songs in iTunes and sync again.  Worked for me.

Comment: Do you need to have "only sync checked songs" selected or de-selected for this? My guess would be the former.

Answer (score 1):

Some media cannot be played by the iPod *even if the format is already* AAC (`.m4a` in Finder). I've experienced this with **media that was not directly purchased in the iTunes store**. This broke the syncing and I ended up calling  Apple Care Support.

What worked in the end was to **convert** all songs that were not purchased directly in iTunes to **AAC using iTunes** (right-click menu).

Then update your lists and try to sync them to the iPod again.

[image]

You really need to make sure that you have the right songs in the lists. Because I now had two AAC versions of the same song, I had to make sure that I only keep the version that iTunes created:

1. Select the song
2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Get Info)
3. Go to the tab **summary** and confirm that **Encoded with** says **iTunes 10.X**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was because my iPod was synced to a library on a different computer. I had to resync with my current computer. The iPod will only sync with one iTunes library. In iTunes, select your iPod and synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

I was with apple support for probably 20 minutes on the phone and even screen sharing. She had me uninstall all itunes and apple first, restart my computer and reinstall. So that might be part 1. Part 2 was that in the music section when your ipod is connected, there is a button that says sync music and gives you the option of selecting the whole library or only checked albums, artists etc. I had to hit that sync button instead of the one that pops up when you connect the ipod. That worked with me so just dicking around solved the problem. If anything make an apt. with the apple store.